# QThreadStorage double free

Tags: qt

Qt5.12.12 with msvc 2017 x64.
I create a QThreadStorage object at the beginning of my app, when I close my app, it crashs. After debug, I find it is caused by double free of the data in QThreadStorage. Here is my code. Am I use it wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QThreadStorage<QString> data;
    data.setLocalData("TEst");


    QMainWindow window;
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And here is error information and trace stack.

[Error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhlXw.png)

[trace stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj9k5.png)